# MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait freezing my app

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

```
self.catContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
Cat *cat = [Cat MR_createEntityInContext:self.catContext];

[self doSomething:@"someText" completion:^(NSDictionary *results) {
                if (results) {
                    cat.name = results[@"name"];
                    [cat.managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
                }
            }];
```

The app freezes, and Xcode is paused on the MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait line, which is running on com.apple.main-thread. Why the freezing, and how to fix?

EDIT:
If I replace that line with this:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

The app no longer freezes. However, when I go to access the cat later, none of the information got saved to the Cat (name, etc.).

Comment: How many records are you creating/changing?  A lot?  Do you have a background thread that is saving a context at the same time?  In general doing a save shouldn't block indefinitely--but it might seem that way if you have a lot of changes to make.  But if another context has a lock on the persistent store, this could cause your other save to block.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` or some up-to-date equivalent and update your UI in the completion block?

Comment: saveInBackgroundWithBlock is deprecated. I don't know why MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait exists if I can't use it in situations like this.

Comment: There must be something equivalent to `performBlock` as opposed to `performBlockAndWait`, with a completion block. I don't use the MR framework (it does not simplify anything). Check the docs.